# Confused by asynchronous mechanism

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am confused by the fact that android is multi-threaded. If the code of a particular activity method is executing, can it be interrupted in the middle by `onPause()`, `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` or by another method like the `onPostExecute()` of an asynctask?

### Edit 1

This question is not about activities life-cycle. What i am really asking is if the onPause() method can interrupt the onClick() method (just an example) and i would like to read more about how exactly android manages activities, calls their async methods etc...

### Edit 2

Ok, it seems that i have found the relevant information i needed in the developer docs (don't know if it is explained better somewhere else): [Threading Performance](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html):

> Internals
>
> The main thread has a very simple design: Its only job is to take and
>   execute blocks of work from a thread-safe work queue until its app is
>   terminated. The framework generates some of these blocks of work from
>   a variety of places. These places include callbacks associated with
>   lifecycle information, user events such as input, or events coming
>   from other apps and processes. In addition, app can explicitly enqueue
>   blocks on their own, without using the framework.

It states that callbacks relative to activity lifecycle, user events such as input and other code are all managed using a "thread-safe work queue". This is central to understanding Android asynchronous programming. It explains a lots of things, such as why onClick() will be never be interrupted by activity onPause(), or why onClick() will be never be interrupted by a runnable posted using a Handler object (allocated in the main thread). So, for example, the onPostExecute() of an AsyncTask cannot interrupt the onClick() method (or onStart(), onResume(), onPause() etc...). As a novice android programmer, it was a bit confusing at first.

Comment: You can't interrupt Activity's life cycle. On other hand AsyncTask is just thread implementation with callback on UI thread . It has nothing to do with Activity  lifecycle.(As much as i know, Correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: Suppose the onClick() method of the activity is executing and for some reason the onPause() method have to be called. Will android interrupt the onClick() method to execute onPause()?

Comment: onClick and on pause never going to trigger at same time . And is asynctask is already started then it will be running even after pause and stop.

Comment: @ADM Ok. Do you have any reference to support what you say? I really would like to read about the exact mechanism behind this asynchronous calls.

Comment: Well i am still learning so you can search on that or you can tag @Commansware to ask him. He can explain it better .

Comment: @berlusca I think this link might be useful for you 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, I think you need to understand basic about Android Application's life cycle.

Basically, the life cycle deals with the state of application in different different situation. 
Like what will be state when application goes, in foreground or background and all that So These cycles state that you had mentioned like `onPause()`,`onDestroy()`, `onStart()`, `onCreate()`.

Now talk for `AsynchTask()`, If you want to execute long running process like downloading image or listening musing or any other then we will use BackGround services. So don't get confusion between life cycle method and background services. .

Third, App will close only some rare condition like if memory is not sufficient or some other fatal issue occur in App then only it will terminate.

**So, findings are that Thread is meant for long running process and Activity Life Cycles method are meant for various activity state**

[Please follow this tutorial and I hope you will get clarification](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: OK, but can onPause() be called by android system in the middle of execution of another activity method? I ask this because it is an asynchronous event, right?

Comment: OnPause() is called when the user receives an event like a call or a text message, when onPause() is called the Activity may be partially or completely hidden.

You would want to save user data in onPause, in case he hits back button without saving the data explicitly

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question to ask I think. However, Here is my understanding:

When an Application starts, a Dalvik Virtual Machine (DVM) is assigned to it and works separately. So no two Applications interrupt each other as each of the application is managed by separate DVM.

Coming to Activity, it is a component of Android and runs on main thread. Android OS manages priority level to it's components. It gives high priority level to Activity, Services and may be other component(s). The OS maintains the non interruption behaviour of main thread.

Further when you run an AsyncTask, it is a long running task in background but dependent on Application context. So the OS does not guarantee to manage it.

Now regarding activity life cycle. As @nihal_softy said, activity has it's own life cycle which start from onCreate() and encounters onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy(). You can call these methods from anywhere of your Activity or from an AsyncTask and it will called but does not mean that the Activity will go in background or will destroy. In a simpler word, if you call onPause() from an AsyncTask, it does not mean that the Activity will be sent to background (if in foreground). Because when an Activity will go in background then it calls it's life cycle methods such as onPause() and onStop() as callback. But converse is not true.

I hope my understanding will help you to get the answer.

Comment: Yes, but i was specifically asking about the mechanism used by Android to call my activity onPause(). I have made a little experiment: an activity with a button. When i press the button, the onClick method is called. It does some time-consuming task. Meanwhile i press the home button. The onPause method is not called until the onClick method has finished. I was asking about this mechanism. For example, if the AsyncTask.onPostExecute method do a time-consuming task and i press the home button, the activity onPause() is not called until the onPostExecute is finished.

Comment: Just to inform you that when you press home button onPause() will be called just after that only which Android life cycle says. I was sure but yet I tested once for you and log in onPause() has been called just after I have clicked home button. Further, when you are doing a long running task in your button click, it should work in some other thread only otherwise you app will get stuck due to keep UI thread as busy. Now if you are using some other thread like AsyncTask related thing, main thread will do it's own job and onPause() will be called just after pressing home button.

Comment: In my test, my activity onPause() method is not called until the onClick method has finished its computations. And i think that it is the only way to correctly handle asynchronous calls (i just would like to read more in the official docs about the exact mechanism implemented by android, but can't find it). By the way, it was just a test, not that i am normally doing time-consuming code that way.

Comment: On developer site you will see something like, "onPause() is where you deal with the user leaving your activity. Most importantly, any changes made by the user should at this point be committed (usually to the ContentProvider holding the data)." This means when you are pressing Home button and your screen is going invisible, onPause will be called just after that.

Comment: Appreciate the question came into your mind, it is necessary to get depth knowledge of anything. However, please like and accept my answer if it gave the answer of your question and related concept. Thanks